# Magento 2 - Error the specified key does not exist on Amazon aws cdn

Tags: magento2, amazon-web-services, cloudfront-cdn

We have created an account in amazon Aws.

We have *replace the secure base url for static and media files* with the domain name that is shown in the *AWS distribution*.

The site is not showing correctly and also the images is not showing.

My website is developed in magento 2.2.2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you syncing your media to S3 from the Magento Servers? I have found better response times using EFS for media if there is not too many products.

According to AWS the file is not uploaded to S3 bucket. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/404-error-nosuchkey-s3/

Try checking the S3 bucket for the existence of this file.